# How can I copy an entire directory in Perl?

Tags: perl, copy, directory-structure

I need to copy entire directory to some location.

What is the best way to do so ? `File::Copy` copies only file by file as I saw it.

By the way I work under Windows.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe look into [File::Copy::Recursive](http://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Recursive).

Comment: Just gives "Can't locate File/Copy/Recursive.pm". This solution is based on the precondition that the library has been installed. Any other solution beside using system()?

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search for ["perl copy directory file::"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=perl+copy+directory+file%3A%3A) finds

[File::Copy::Recursive](http://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Recursive)

Looks what you're after.