# How can I copy an entire directory in Perl, without using File::Copy::Recursive?

Tags: perl, recursion, copy, directory-structure

### Question:

My question is pretty much identical to [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865883/how-can-i-copy-an-entire-directory-in-perl) except that I cannot use  File::Copy::Recursive.

#### Constraints:

I cannot install or modify the existing environment, so I am stuck with using what works.

```
use File::Copy;   # Works!
use File::Copy::Recursive # Doesn't Work :(
use File::Path # Works!
```

I get this error: (*I cannot fix this error, since I am only a user of this system, not admin or anything*)
`Can't locate File/Copy/Recursive.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /path/to/some/place /path/to/other/place .) at my_program.pl line 13.`

#### Scenario:

If it helps, my scenario is that I want to copy the contents directory, lets say `~/my_dir` onto what already exists here `~/`. `~/my_dir` has a sub-folder `~/my_dir/sub_dir` and I want to copy that directory and all of it's contents too.

Comment: Re "I cannot install or modify the existing environment", So you can't add Perl code to the machine?

Comment: The source of [`File::Copy::Recursive`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Recursive)is [here](https://metacpan.org/source/DMUEY/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm).. It uses modules `File::Copy` and `File::Spec` .. You can just copy it to your local machine

Comment: Does it have to be perl? `rsync`, `cp` or `tar` can do directory structure copies.

Comment: It must be perl. I am currently investigating @HåkonHægland comment.

Comment: Are copying a directory that contains no link nodes to another brand new directory that is initially empty? If so then it is fairly simple, and the many tests that `File::Copy::Recursive::dircopy` makes are Unnecessary. It becomes a call to `File::Find::find` with appropriate use of use of `File::Spec->abs2rel`, `File::Spec->rel2abs`, `File::Path::make_path` and `File::Copy::copy`. If you confirm that your situation matches this reduced problem then I will write up a solution

Comment: I didn't get that far with File:Copy, and just switched my approach to @ikegami 's Answer. I think for posterity, the link to the source in File::Copy, and using a reduced featureset since it has a lot of check I didn't need, is the 'correct' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system's tools are way better at this anyway.

```
system('cp', '-rp', '--', $src, $dst);
die("Can't launch cp: $!\n") if $? == -1;
die("cp killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("cp exited with error ".($? >> 8)."\n") if $? >> 8;
```

The downside is the lack of portability. If you want portability, install File::Copy::Recursive. If you can install your script on a machine, you can also install File::Copy::Recursive.

Comment: I require portability, which is my I didn't simply use a shell script. I cannot install `File::Copy::Recursive` on the target machine.

Comment: Only in the sense you didn't do it right if you tried.

Comment: I can't be sure what is available to me on the destination machine. (*Eg. bash shell handles flow control with different syntax than ksh*)

You make a point, that for this specific piece of the puzzle, I can probably assume the `cp` command is available. I'll test it and get back to you.

Comment: No shell was involved in that use of `system`.

Comment: I was able to use this to accomplish my goal.